# Can't get AWS CLI Command to run in Jenkins script

Tags: jenkins, sh, aws-cli, jmespath

I am running a AWS command and attempting to capture the command

```
weight = sh (
            script: """
            aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
            --hosted-zone-id ${HOSTED_ZONE_ID} \
            --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Type == 'A' && Name == ${RECORD_NAME} && SetIdentifier == ${IDENTIFIER}].Weight"
            """,
            returnStdout: true
        )
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ABCABCABCABC --query 'ResourceRecordSets[?Type == '\''A'\'' && Name == test-e1-qa.aws.com. && SetIdentifier == test-qa-e1].Weight'
Bad value for --query ResourceRecordSets[?Type: Invalid jmespath expression: Incomplete expression:
"ResourceRecordSets[?Type"
```

But if I run the command in terminal, it works fine:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ABCABCABCABC --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Type == 'A' && Name == 'test-e1-qa.aws.com.' && SetIdentifier == 'test-qa-e1'].Weight"
```

It looks like something is wrong with how it is processing quotes, but I am not sure how to fix it. I tried using replacing the double quotes surround the `ResourceRecordSets` with `"\""` or `/x22`, but it still throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the quotes issue, you can try below pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage ('getweight') {
            agent any

            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
                HOSTED_ZONE_ID=12345abcd
                RECORD_NAME="'test.example.com.'"
                aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ${HOSTED_ZONE_ID} --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Type == 'A' && Name == ${RECORD_NAME} && SetIdentifier == 'test'].Weight"
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (getweight)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[testpipline] Running shell script
[
    200
]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```